# Certificate Transparency and S/MIME certificates

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, smime, certificate-transparency

When people speak about CT that usually means only TLS certificates are stored in log. However, CT probable might be considered for usage in other PKI-based technologies.

- Is CT designed to log S/MIME certificates?
- Does any benefits or restrictions exist to populate CT logs with S/MIME certificates?

Comment: Not sure. Digicert says in a [2017 blog that you can't log S/MIME certs](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/what-is-certificate-transparency/). But I don't see why not. And there was a talk at Real World Crypto 2018 about the idea of generalizing the CT concept to just about anything: the ["Trillian" project](https://twitter.com/rmhrisk/status/951987296286502917). So I don't think there's a technical reason for not allowing S/MIME certs. I also found a GitHub project that seems to be about doing just that: ["email2certs"](https://github.com/SSLMate/email2certs).

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff, yes, I also saw that. I am interested in a reasoning behind that. One possible limitation is that e-mail addresses contained in S/MIME certs might be exposed in a central repository.

Comment: Yeah. Seems like a reasonable assumption.